# Room message not being shown with Socket.io & Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express, socket.io

index.js

```js
socket.on('join room', function(data) {
  var msg = "<span style='color:darkgreen;'>" + data.user + " has joined chat.</span>";
  socket.to(data.room).emit('system message', msg);
});
```

index.html

```js
$(function() {
  socket.on('system message', function(msg) {
        $('#messages').append($('<div class="systemMessage">').html(msg));
        var height = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;
        $.mobile.silentScroll(height);
  });
});
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#channel", function ( e ) {
  var socket = io();
  if (getCookie("username") == "null") {
   $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#login-page", {
    transition: "pop"
   } );
  }
  else {
   socket.emit('join room', { room: getCookie("currentRoom"), user: getCookie("username") });
   $("#enter-sound").get(0).play();
  }
});
```

So for whatever reason, when changing channels, it is not showing the "system message" that gets sent when a user joins a new channel via the on 'join room' & 'system message" emits. Anyone have any thoughts as to why this might be? I put an alert style debugger in there and it does not show the javascript alert when system message socket.on is triggered.

Comment: Side note: i've tried `io.in(data.room)` as well. Still didn't send the message to index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `io.in(data.room)` isn't accepted because `data.room` is a javascript object and not a string. so I just added and it worked:

```js
var room = data.room;
room = room.toString();
```